# Pugh's exercise on Dedekind cuts addition

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $x=A|B$ and $x'=A'|B'$ be cuts in $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that although $B+B'$ is disjoint from $A+A'$, it may happen in degenerate cases that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not the union of $A+A'$ and $B+B'$.

The first assertion is straightforward, but I have not been able to handle the second one. It does not work for rational cuts or $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Try $\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$. More generally, try any two irrationals whose sum is rational.

Comment: Brian, thanks for your beautiful answer. If $x=A|B$ and $x'=A'|B'$ are irrational cuts, and $x+x'=C|D$ is rational, then $B+B'\subsetneqq D$ because $B+B'$ has no smallest element, but $D$ does. That is all I needed.

Comment: @Luoisv: You’re welcome.